# Authorship order changed after resubmitting to another journal?

Tags: publications, ethics, authorship

The work is a collaboration between my home university and another research group. We first submitted the work to a pretty good journal **where I was the second author.** But the publisher recommended we submit it to a different/ more suitable journal, and I found out I'm  **fifth author now.** I'm just an undergrad, so I don't want to step on toes before I apply for a PhD.

**Edit:** The other group made the change. The corresponding prof from the other group was last author earlier but is now first (they are still the corresponding author)

Comment: Who made the change? Why was it made?

Comment: Edited the post. 
But I'm not sure why they made the change.

Comment: Did they make any changes to the paper or just submit the same paper to a lower journal?

Comment: I'm not sure. The final version wasn't shared with me (even though I wrote half the paper). They submitted it to a lower journal.

Comment: Please add a question to your post.  Currently it appears to be a statement.

Comment: The final version should have been shared with all authors.  Yikes.

Comment: @TerryLoring Yep. As corresponding author, the first thing I do with *all* correspondence is copy all other authors into it, if they aren't already. Man waving red flag alert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an undergraduate you probably have little power to change things. That would be a task for your local PI or supervisor. However, it feels like a selfish move on the part of the other group, especially if done without explanation and consultation.

But any good publication as an undergraduate, no matter the author order, will be a plus for graduate admissions.

A talk with the local supervisor to ask "is this OK?" would, perhaps give you some insight, even if it doesn't lead to a change. And you are right to keep a low profile here.